# Gatsby can't find client routes when using gatsby-plugin-react-i18next

Tags: gatsby, i18next, reach-router

I'm using client routes in Gatsby together with `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next`. When I'm trying to access one of the client routes while not using the default language, e.g. the url is prefixed with `/sv`, then I get that the route doesn't exists. If I add the prefix `/sv` to the router basepath, the `Default` component/path is working but not the `Profile` component/path.

While using the default language without the `/sv` prefix, everything is working as expected.

*src/pages/account.tsx*

```
<Router basepath={'/account'}>
  <AccountRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
  <Default path="/" />
</Router>
```

*gatsby-node.js*

```
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  if (page.path.match(/^\/account/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/account/*"

    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

I've also tried to add the prefix `/sv` to the `matchPath` in *gatsby-node.js* but then I'm redirected to double prefixes `/sv/sv` route that doesn't exists. If I tell `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next` to not generate language pages for the account pages, I get the same result.

*gatsby-config.js*

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next`,
  options: {
    ...
  },
  pages: [
    {
      matchPath: '/:lang?/account/(.*)',
      getLanguageFromPath: true
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this still active? You've missed some configurations and some are not needed: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/ Just read the docs carefully.

Comment: It is! I still remember the good old days getting Linux to run where the answer to every question was RTFM. The great thing about SO is that it's not a manual but a fast lookup table.
However, I've read the page you have linked and there is no mention of how the gatsby i18next plugin deals with client-side routing problems. If you know an answer, your input is still appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We want to solve:

1. getting the lang prefix to work
2. getting the default page (no lang prefix) to work

For this, I currently used this solution:

`gatsby-node.js`:

```
function langPrefix(page) {
  return page.context.language === page.context.i18n.defaultLanguage &&
    !page.context.i18n.generateDefaultLanguagePage
    ? ''
    : `/${page.context.language}`
}



exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  // Removing the ^ skips an optional /:lang prefix
  if (page.path.match(/\/app/)) {
    // adding lang if it's not the default page.
    page.matchPath = `${langPrefix(page)}/app/*`
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

Additionally, I duplicated routes to handle the cases with and without lang prefix:

```
<...>
  {/* Version for default language (no /:lang/ in path) */}
  <Router basepath={`/app`}>
    <ViewerWrapper path="/:myProp" />
  </Router>
  {/* Version for explicit language (/:lang/ in path) */}
  <Router basepath={`/:lang/app`}>
    <ViewerWrapper path="/:myProp" />
  </Router>
</...>
```

Now keep the simplifications coming :)

Props to [Mario Skrlec](https://newbedev.com/how-to-create-dynamic-route-in-gatsby) and [ozburo](https://github.com/microapps/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/issues/69#issuecomment-843613097) for their approaches.

Comment: I did the same configuration as you mentioned. However http://localhost:8000/en-us/app/page1  it show an error There's not a page or function yet at /en-us/app/page1. Any pointers?

Comment: Also how to get the language translation contents in client only route page ?