# Gatsby V4: How to implement gatsby-plugin-react-i18next for client only routes

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin, reach-router

I'm trying to implement client routes in Gatsby together with gatsby-plugin-react-i18next for two languages. I followed officel Gataby documentation and there is no client only path implementation explained.

Below is the code i implemeted.

```
gatsby-node.js
   function langPrefix(page) {
      return page.context.language === page.context.i18n.defaultLanguage &&
        !page.context.i18n.generateDefaultLanguagePage
        ? ''
        : `/${page.context.language}`
    }
    
    
    
    exports.onCreatePage = ({ page, actions }) => {
      const { createPage } = actions
      // Removing the ^ skips an optional /:lang prefix
      if (page.path.match(/\/app/)) {
        // adding lang if it's not the default page.
        page.matchPath = `${langPrefix(page)}/app/*`
        createPage(page)
      }
    }
```

Appjs

```
 src/app/app.js
    function App() {
      return (
        <>
          <Router basepath="/:lang/app">
            <PrivateRoute path="/accounthome" component={AccountHome} location=""/>
          </Router>
          <Router basepath="/app">
            <PrivateRoute path="/accounthome" component={AccountHome} location=""/>
          </Router>
        </>)
    }
    export default App
```

Gatsby config

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next`,
      options: {
        localeJsonSourceName: `locale`, // name given to `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin.
        languages: ["en", "fr"],
        defaultLanguage: `en-us`,
        fallbackLanguage: `en-us`, 
        // if you are using Helmet, you must include siteUrl, and make sure you add http:https
        siteUrl: `https://my.costco.com/`,
        ns: langTranslationConfig,
        // you can pass any i18next options
        i18nextOptions: {
          interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
          },
          nsSeparator: false
        }, 
        pages: [
          {
            matchPath: '/:lang/app/accounthome',
            getLanguageFromPath: true,
            excludeLanguages: ['en-ca']
          },
          {
            matchPath: '/preview',
            languages: ['en']
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Router path : http://localhost:8000/en-us/app/accounthome
When am accessing this rote in browser This code show Gatsby.js development 404 page not found. Any pointer what am missing and am not sure how to access the translation contents in client only route page example account home page. Do i need to write the graph query in account home page or i dont need to ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your regex is leaking your code. I guess it should look like:

```
  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    page.matchPath = `${langPrefix(page)}/app/*`
    createPage(page)
  }
```

Either way, check the created page list by accessing the 404 page in development mode. By default, there should be a list of all created pages. Check the paths there to see if you can spot any mistakes or trailing slash issues.

The problem here is that your page is not being generated properly, that's why it throws a 404, so checking the created pages may help you to spot the mistake or at least, a thread to pull.

After a few research I've seen that you are basing your approach in: [Gatsby can't find client routes when using gatsby-plugin-react-i18next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242212/gatsby-cant-find-client-routes-when-using-gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/69905274#69905274)

In their case, the `langPrefix` function is only prefixing the language to the page slug if it's the default one:

```
function langPrefix(page) {
  return page.context.language === page.context.i18n.defaultLanguage &&
    !page.context.i18n.generateDefaultLanguagePage
    ? ''
    : `/${page.context.language}`
}
```

In your case, I'm not sure the plugin supports `en-us` (it's `en-US` according to https://github.com/microapps/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/issues/100) and I think that's the reason why there's a leak in your page creation. Try using `en` instead of `en-us` or directly looking for `en-US` paths.

Comment: Thanks Ferran, You mean to say client side page will be created in development mode?  my understanding is  client side pages are run time pages ritgh?

Comment: Thanks Ferran, You mean to say client side page will be generated in development mode?  my understanding is  client side pages are run time pages right? I mean to say with out i18 next. The routings were working fine in that case also i was not able to see client page listed in 404 page

Comment: According to the 404 docs it should (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/add-404-page/). Now I see the approach you are trying to implement (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242212/gatsby-cant-find-client-routes-when-using-gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/69905274#69905274), would be nice to know beforehand. The problem is that your `langPrefix` is only prefixing the language if it's default and it should be `en-US` or `en` (see updated answer)